# A ball is launched vertically upward from the ground...?

Tags: calculus

Ok here is the problem:

A ball is launched vertically from the ground with an initial velocity of 96ft/sec.

How can I find the equation or at least how can I start this problem?

Here are some questions related to the problem.

a. How long does it take the ball to rise to the maximum height?
b. What is the maximum height?
c. How long does it take the ball to reach halve the initial velocity?
d. What is the height of the ball when its velocity is half the initial velocity?

Comment: Hont: acceleration = -g, velocity = $\int$ acceleration $=-gt+c$ (use initial conditions to get $c$), position = $\int$ velocity.

Comment: All these are valid for speeds $<<$ escape speed.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781193/velocity-of-a-ball-when-it-hits-the-ground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the value you want to find, the equations may vary - of course, you can always manipulate one to become another through substitution, but I'll try to make it simple; for your question, I'll start with two basic equations.

To start with, we know the gravitational acceleration is $g = 9.81 \frac m {s^2}$ or $g = 32.19 \frac m {s^2}$, and from basic kinematics, the velocity at any time is modeled by $v_f = v_0 + at$ where $v_f$ is the final velocity, $v_0$ is the initial velocity, $a$ is the acceleration, and $t$ is the time elapsed.

### Equation 1. Change in Velocity

In our case, $a = -g$ as acceleration is downward (characteristics of free fall), so we can substitute in our starting equation to get

$$v_f = v_0 - gt$$

### Equation 2. Change in Position (Displacement)

Also, we know the displacement (net distance traveled) can be found by averaging the initial velocity and the final velocity and then multiplying by the time elapsed, thus

$$\Delta x = \frac {t(v_0 + v_f)} 2$$

And we'll work from there.

#### A. How long does it take the ball to rise to the maximum height?

From common sense, first of all, you can realize that, at maximum height, the ball's velocity is $v_f = 0 \frac m s$ (it's essentially not moving, as its maximum height is right where the ball stops moving up and starts moving down. Before we substitute quickly: I think it's good practice to solve for $t$ symbolically first, so let's do that:

\begin{align*}
     v_f &= v_0 - gt            \quad && \text{Start with first equation} \\
v_f + gt &= v_0                 \quad && \text{Add $gt$ to both sides} \\
      gt &= v_0 - v_f           \quad && \text{Subtract $v_f$ from both sides} \\
       t &= \frac {v_0 - v_f} g \quad && \text{Divide both sides by $g$ (4)} \\
       t &= \frac {v_0} g       \quad && \text{Here, we know $v_f = 0$}
\end{align*}

Then, you can easily find $t$ by substituting $v_0$, $v_f$, and $g$ - all of which are given.

#### B. What is the maximum height?

For this case, we can use the second equation and solve for $\Delta x$ after substituting for $v_0$ and $v_f$, which are given, and $t$ which we can get from the equation above. Substituting and simplifying, we get:

\begin{align*}
\Delta x &= \frac {t(v_0 + v_f)} 2              \quad && \text{Start with second equation} \\
\Delta x &= \frac {(v_0 - v_f)(v_0 + v_f)} {2g} \quad && \text{Substitute for $t$ and simplify} \\
\Delta x &= \frac {v_0^2 - v_f^2} {2g}          \quad && \text{"Expand" polynomial (3)} \\
\Delta x &= \frac {v_0^2} {2g}                  \quad && \text{Here, we know $v_f = 0$}
\end{align*}

#### C. How long does it take the ball to reach half the initial velocity?

Although seemingly trickier, this is really not much harder at all than **Question A** - in fact, much of the work has already been done in that question; we can directly start from the fourth step of the solution to **Question A** (labeled in parentheses), where we have solved for $t$. Here, $v_f = \frac {v_0} 2$.

\begin{align*}
t &= \frac {v_0 - v_f} g           \quad && \text{Start with equation in step 4 of A} \\
t &= \frac {v_0 - \frac {v_0} 2} g \quad && \text{Substitute for $v_f$} \\
t &= \frac {\frac {v_0} 2} g       \quad && \text{Simplify} \\
t &= \frac {v_0} {2g}              \quad && \text{More simplify}
\end{align*}

#### D. What is the height of the ball when its velocity is half the initial velocity?

Again, this is just like **Question B**. Therefore, we can start with the equation in the third step of the solution to **Question B**.

\begin{align*}
\Delta x &= \frac {v_0^2 - v_f^2} {2g}             \quad && \text{Start with equation in step 3 of B} \\
\Delta x &= \frac {v_0^2 - (\frac {v_0} 2)^2} {2g} \quad && \text{Substitute for $v_f$} \\
\Delta x &= \frac {v_0^2 - \frac {v_0^2} 4} {2g}   \quad && \text{Simplify} \\
\Delta x &= \frac {\frac {3v_0^2} 4} {2g}          \quad && \text{More simplify} \\
\Delta x &= \frac {3v_0^2} {8g}                    \quad && \text{Even more simplify}
\end{align*}

And there we have it - the solutions to each of the four problems.

Comment: wow, this was a really good answer. I had to double-take when I saw you only had 36 rep.

Comment: Thanks, I'm (kinda) new and, by chance, found a lucky question (a question that seemed easy for me to answer), so I took at it ;)

Comment: Good explanation, but now you've done this student's homework for him, when what he actually asked was how to get started!

Comment: Uhm... ;p on the bright side, he still has the pleasure of plugging the values in and calculator work for himself...?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to know the basic equations in Newtonian mechanics, e.g.

$$s = ut + \frac{1}{2} . at^2$$

(where $s$ is distance, $u$ is initial velocity, $a$ is acceleration and $t$ is time)

and

$$v = u + at$$

(where $u$ is initial velocity, $v$ is final velocity, $a$ is acceleration and $t$ is time)

And you need to know the acceleration due to gravity ($g$), which is around $32 ft/s^2$.
See here for more accurate figures:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity

(but, judging from the initial velocity being a multiple of 32, I think we can assume that 32 is accurate enough)

As this question is tagged 'calculus', it may be important to note that the first equation above can be obtained by integrating the second.